# NSManagedObject sharedInstance

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton, nsmanagedobject, nsobject

I am trying to make my class 'User' to be an NSManagedObject and be sharedInstance at the same time. However, when I call my `[User sharedInstance]` I get **CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'User'**.

Is it okay to treat NSManagedObject like regular NSObjects and have custom properties and methods on it?

User.h

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isLoggedIn;

+ (instancetype)currentUser;
```

---

User.m

```
@synthesize Id;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize isLoggedIn;

+ (instancetype)currentUser {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t t;
    dispatch_once(&t, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the *managed object* and *singleton* idioms mix very well. They also serve a essentially different purposes, maybe that is the reason.

You need access to your current user from anywhere in the app. That is a quite common use case. A well tested and clean method is to retain a reference to the object in the app delegate (or your Core Data stack class). I personally prefer to just store some unique ID in `NSUserDefaults` and return a `currentUser` dynamically either from the class or the app delegate.

Be aware, that you will likely need several instances of the same "current user" if you use **background contexts** (another reason why the singleton pattern does not fit). One convenient way is to have a `class` method that takes a context and a unique identifier and returns the appropriate `User` object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for `NSManagedObject`'s [- initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)

> IMPORTANT This method is the designated initializer for
>   NSManagedObject. You must not initialize a managed object simply by
>   sending it init.